# What is the order of running these sql scripts?

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have 2 sql scripts ...1 to create a package, The other to create a package body.
Which script should be run first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about Oracle PL/SQL Packages.  You should create the package before you create the package body: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm.